# How to display two different images coming from backend in different image views in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am trying to post two images in one URL I have two different buttons and two image views, both are uploading and both are coming from backend but only one image is changing if I uninstall and again installing the app the image is coming, and I'm using third party sd web image. If any Answers it would be appreciated.

```
NSString *imageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseObject valueForKey:@"Vendor_Image"]];
NSString *imageStr1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseObject valueForKey:@"Vendor_Cover_Image"]];

if([imageStr isEqualToString:@""])
{

    [_userImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];

}
else
{

    [_userImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr]
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];

    _userImage.clipsToBounds = YES;

}

if([imageStr1 isEqualToString:@""])
{

    [_coverImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];

}
else
{

    [_coverImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr1]
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];
    _coverImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use the `sd_setImageWithURL:...` that have a completionBlock, you might get more info on why it's not working. Also, if `imageStr` is non-valid, you still can use `sd_setImageWithURL:` and set the `placeHolderImage`, not needs to do an if/else. Finally, are you sure that `imageStr1` & `imageStr` are valid? Because, I'd strongly recommend to NOT use `valueForKey:`, and printing the values could help in debug.

Comment: You code looks fine. Try to print value of `imageStr` and `imageStr1` and copy paste that url in browser. If image loads successfully then URL works well if not then there's some issue with URL.

Comment: hai kuldeep already I did that its loading successfully but in my image view its not displaying before image only showing.

Comment: @santoshi For both the imageViews you are loading two different urls and you are getting same images for both, Is that the issue ?

Comment: No Anuraj different images only one image loading fine but another image view its not displaying before image only showing

Comment: @Larme Thank you yours sollution is Working Perfect .